# How do I get Excel AutoFill an "advanced" pattern?

Tags: microsoft-excel, auto-form-fill

How can I get Excel to AutoFill a pattern as follows (including the leading zero if needed):

```
010001
011001
012001
020001
021001
022001
...
990001
991001
992001
```

I can't get Excel to respect the leading zero or detect this pattern.
Is there a trick to it?

Comment: What Excel version are you using? -- You need to format that column as *text* and re-enter those values. There are some tricks like using *text in columns* to re-enter whole columns.

Comment: I've tried using Excel 2003 for Windows XP (this is the main version it needs to work on) and on Excel 2011 for Mac. I've tried formatting the cell as _text_, but then it just fills down, copying cells from above rather than incrementing the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you start in row 1, type in the following formula:

```
=TEXT((INT((ROW()-1)/3)+1),"00")&MOD(ROW()-1,3)&"001"
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you use 2 helping columns and delete them afterwards.

- Format Column A + B as text and fill column A with auto increment.
- fill down column B while holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to avoid auto increment
- use a simple formula like `=A1+B1` to concat your strings and fill down column C
- copy column C using only the values

  [image]

Answer (score 2):

If you need it to look like that for display purposes only then here's one way:

Put `10` in A1 then in A2 to A4 use these 3 formulas

`=A1+1`
`=A2+1`
`=A3+8`

Now select `A2:A4` together and drag down as far as required

custom format whole column as `000"001"`

Answer (score -2):

Put a `'` infront of you zero to display the leading zero.

e.g.

`'0123` would display as `123` in Excel.