# Autofill Of Specific Series?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I haven't been able to get Excel 2013 to recognize and autofill the rest of this
all the way down to the bottom of the page.

```
Series
101
103
105
107
109
111
201
203
205
207
209
211
301
303
*continue down
```

I would think it would recognize the series without a formula.

Comment: That's a kind of arbitrary series, so it's no big surprise Excel can't recognize it.  So aside from telling us that you think it should be able to, what's your actual question to us?

Comment: You might want to just fill the series in parts, one column the hundreds and another column the tens and ones, then combine them

Comment: Oops! I never actually asked a question, which would have been, "How can I get Excel 2013 to auto fill this sequence down the page without using a formula." Thanks for the quick response, though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get Excel AutoFill an "advanced" pattern?](http://superuser.com/questions/539302/how-do-i-get-excel-autofill-an-advanced-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start with 101 in row 1, enter

```
=(1+INT((ROW()-1)/6))*100 + MOD(ROW()-1,6)*2 + 1
```

and drag/fill down.  If you want to start in some other row,
adjust the `ROW()-n` subexpressions accordingly. 
To make the results permanent, Copy and Paste Values.